# Railsの「params」というメソッドがよく分からない

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

こんにちは、Ruby初心者で恐縮ですが、Railsを勉強していて、コントローラー内で使っている一見ハッシュのように見える`params[xxx]`が気になって仕方がないのです。

ハッシュじゃないのにあたかもハッシュのような書き方になっています。`ActionController::Parameters`のインスタンスであること以外何も分からなくてちょっと気持ち悪いです。

これってjsの言うところの「**array like object**」的なものなのでしょうか？実際どうやって作られているのでしょうか？できれば簡単なサンプルコードを頂ければ幸いです。

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> ハッシュじゃないのにあたかもハッシュのような書き方になっています

Rails 4 では、 ActionController::Parameters の親クラスの親クラスがHashです。
つまり、ハッシュと継承関係にあるのでハッシュと同じように振る舞います。

```
# ActionController::Parameters
class Parameters < ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess

# ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
class HashWithIndifferentAccess < Hash
```

> これってjsの言うところの「array like object」的なものなのでしょうか？

"array like object"という用語が初耳だったので、こちらのページを読んでみました。

http://nfriedly.com/techblog/2009/06/advanced-javascript-objects-arrays-and-array-like-objects/

なるほど、「Arrayと同じメソッドをいくつか持っているが、完全な互換性はないオブジェクト」のことを指すようですね。

その定義からすると、ActionController::Parametersは"Array(Hash) like object"ではありません。
ハッシュを継承しているので、 "ActionController::Parameters is a Hash"と言えます。
つまりハッシュと完全な互換性があります。（後述するキーの扱いを除いて）

なお、Rails5では、使い方によっては安全のためのフラグがクリアされてしまうなど、パラメータへのアクセス以外のメソッド(Enumerable由来のものなど)が使えてしまうことの弊害があることから、 ActionController::parameters は HashWithIndifferentAccess のサブクラスではなくなっています。([PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/14384) / [コミット(一部)](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/14a3bd520dd4bbf1247fd3e0071b59c02c115ce0))

> 実際どうやって作られているのでしょうか？できれば簡単なサンプルコードを頂ければ幸いです。

クラス定義は上に載せたとおりです。詳しくはRailsのコードを読んでみてください。

- https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters/blob/master/lib/action_controller/parameters.rb
- https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/hash_with_indifferent_access.rb

インスタンスの作り方という点では、以下のように new + keyとvalue でインスタンスを作成できます。
（とはいえ、自分でActionController::Parametersをnewすることは滅多にないですが）

```
params = ActionController::Parameters.new(name: 'Alice', email: 'alice@example.com') 
=> {"name"=>"Alice", "email"=>"alice@example.com"}
```

ハッシュと同じように扱えるので、keyとvalueを追加することもで来ます。

```
params['tel'] = '123456'
=> "123456"
```

ただし、HashWithIndifferentAccess（ActionController::Parametersの親クラス）はkeyとしてシンボルと文字列を区別しないようにハッシュを拡張しています。

```
params[:name]
"Alice"

params['name'] 
"Alice"

params['tel']
"123456"

params[:tel]
"123456"
```

ちなみにRails本体でActionController::Parametersのインスタンスを作成しているコードは以下のようになっています。

```
# https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters/blob/master/lib/action_controller/parameters.rb
module ActionController
  # ...
  module StrongParameters
    # ...
    def params
      @_params ||= Parameters.new(request.parameters)
    end
```

`def params` がcontrollerでよく登場する `params` の正体です。

こんな感じで疑問点は解消されたでしょうか？
他に不明な点があればコメントください。

**P.S.**

余談ですがこういう疑問を持ったときはRubyMineのコードジャンプ機能を使うと便利です。
有料のIDEですが、使いこなせばデバッグやコードリーディングの時間をかなり節約できるので、導入を検討してみると良いかもしれません。

- [RubyMineのコードジャンプ機能は本当にすごい！！困ったときはCommand+Bを押すべし！](http://qiita.com/jnchito/items/bcb2bb5311a44113fdd9)
- [僕がRubyMineを使い始めたたった１つの理由](http://qiita.com/LuckOfWise/items/c961a046d40a20436932)

僕もこの回答を書くにあたり、RubyMineを使ってクラスやメソッドの定義元を探していきました。

Comment: 源は`HashWithIndifferentAccess`にあったのですね！なるほどなるほど！
RubyMineのおすすめありがとうございます。

Comment: Rails5ではAC::ParametersがHashの子孫ではなくなっているので、本文を若干修正させていただきました。

Answer (score 3):

Rubyでは`hash[key]`や`hash[key]=x`のように[一見すると演算子のように見えるメソッド呼び出し](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.2.0/doc/spec=2foperator.html)がいくつかあります。

これらのメソッドを再定義すると、JavaScriptでいうところのarray like objectのような、`Hash`クラスではないが`[]`や`[]=`のインターフェイスを備えたクラスを実装できます。

```rb
class Foo
  def initialize
    @hash = {}
  end

  def []=(key, value)
    @hash[key] = value * 2
  end

  def [](key)
    @hash[key] * 2
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
foo["bar"] = 10
p foo["bar"]

# => 40
```

Rubyの組み込みライブラリだと[ENV](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.2.0/class/ENV.html)などが、ハッシュと同様のインターフェイスを持ったオブジェクトとして実装されています。

```rb
p ENV["USER"] # => your_user_name
p ENV.class # => Object
```

### 参考

- [演算子式](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.2.0/doc/spec=2foperator.html)
- [クラス／メソッドの定義](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.2.0/doc/spec=2fdef.html#operator)
- [object ENV](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.2.0/class/ENV.html)

Comment: ふむふむ！メソッドを演算子のような名前にすればシンタックスシュガーが勝手に適用されるということなのですね！

ご回答ありがとうございます！大変分かりやすかったです。

Answer (score 2):

`params` は、Rails 由来のものです。

`params` は、 `Action Controller.Parameters` オブジェクトで、まるでハッシュをもつハッシュのように扱えます。Rails は、アクセスされた URL をルーティングルールに従い分割して `Parameters` オブジェクトを作成しており、`params` の主な役割としてはそこから必須属性、使用する属性をチェック・振り分けることになります。また、以下のように自分で作成することもできます。`params` の詳しい使い方は、[Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters)を参照するのがよいでしょう。

```
params = ActionController::Parameters.new({
  person: {
    name: 'Francesco',
    age:  22,
    role: 'admin'
  }
})
new_params = params.require(:person).permit(:name, :age)
new_params            # => {"name"=>"Francesco", "age"=>22}
```

`params` を純粋なハッシュにするには、`to_h`, `to_unsafe_h` を使用します。  
以下、[Rails のソースコードから抜粋](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5923ee6fe04500ce46f7fc8fff6aafcfd64e68db/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb#L155)します。

```
params = ActionController::Parameters.new({
  name: 'Senjougahara Hitagi',
  oddity: 'Heavy stone crab'
})
params.to_h # => {}

safe_params = params.permit(:name)
safe_params.to_h # => {"name"=>"Senjougahara Hitagi"}
```

`to_h` では、 `permit` の設定で、ハッシュに入るエントリがフィルタにかけられます。例では、`name` しか指定されていませんから、出来上がったハッシュには `oddity` が入っていません。

参考: 
[Ruby on Rails : Action Controller Parameters](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html)  
[Rails Guides: ActionController Overview : Paramemters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters)
[Strong Parameter by Example](http://blog.trackets.com/2013/08/17/strong-parameters-by-example.html)

Comment: `to_h`を使えば普通のハッシュに変換出来るんですね！ためになりました！どうもありがとうございます！